# What do Wordpress' SEO plugins and defaults accomplish?

Tags: seo, google, wordpress

Our site currently sucks, and we're talking about either moving to Wordpress or making a new site. I've basically finished a prototype, but my collegues told me that WP is often better for SEO. I did a little research and found that Wordpress just has better defaults, and useful tools. I thought I could easily replicate everything by myself (and not mess around with someone else's blog skins), but couldn't find what exactly is needed - Google's [webmaster guidelines](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=35769) don't provide any concrete information about meta tags, etc. What do Wordpress plugins actually do?

Comment: Voting to close. There's no real answer to this, being dependent upon *which* plugin you're asking about. At which point: go and read that plugin's documentation to find out what it does. Beyond that, yes you could replicate anything they do, if you take the time to research. They're just making it easier, sometimes significantly, for you to accomplish the tagging, etc. There's nothing special *in itself* about using WordPress or whatever plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress per say isnt better for SEO than any other platform. Some one could make a wp theme that was horrible SEO wise, just because your on wp isnt going to help.

Whats great about word press and this is more for onsite SEO than offsite is its flexibility, and the ease of editing it. This is were plugins help big time.

For instance its url structures by default are set up nicely- ie. mysite.com/mypage instead of mysite.com/auth/ben/123/mypage

You want to add a robots.txt file - easy just download a plugin for it and configure a few easy drop downs and your done.

www. vs non www redirect - again easy, i think its done as default, but if not again plugins, similarly with mysite.com vs mysite.com/index.php

The best SEO tool that will help you configure Title tags aswell as other bits a peices is by [Yoast](http://yoast.com/wordpress/seo/)